# Adding a path after a "-" parameter in Terminal OSX ( crark )

Tags: macos, path, terminal, filepath

I downloaded crark (crark.net) and I need to run it in Terminal. My PATH i think is not sticking so I need to put the destination of everything in it.

**Normally someone would type: crark -c crackme.rar to run the program.**
The program uses a password.def file that is in the same folder as "crark"

**BUT because my path isn't sticking** when I use cd to go to the folder where everything is, I have to type:

/Users/bigtrade/Desktop/crark/nogpu/crark -c **-p Users/bigtrade/Desktop/crark/nogpu/password.def** /Users/bigtrade/Desktop/crark/crack.rar

**THIS PART: -p Users/bigtrade/Desktop/crark/nogpu/password.def GIVES ME this ERROR:**

Cannot open Users/bigtrade/Desktop/crark/nogpu/password.def
No such file or directory

How can I type a path after a "-" parameter ?

Btw: if I don't include the part with -p and the location, the program just says it can't find a password.def file.

Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You've omitted the `/` in front of Users, which it should include. Better yet, try doing this:

```
cd /Users/bigtrade/Desktop/crark/nogpu/
```

then:

```
./crark -c -p password.def ~/desktop/crark/crack.rar
```